# Object value by key return undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have object like the one below and every time i call object["key"] it return undefined for some reason

i tried the following and still getting undefined

```
object.keyName

object[keyName]

object["keyName"]
```

all of them return undefined

```
let sam = {
  "facebook": "https://facebook.com",
  "instagram": "https://Instagram.com",
  "placeName": "dazzlement",
  "snapchat": "https://snapchat.com",
  "twitter": "https://twitter.com",
}
```

let's say i want placeName value 
i tried

```
sam.placeName
sam[placeName]
sam["placeName"]
```

all of them return undefined.

-------- UPDATE ----------

i'm using react native with Parse JS SDK here is the code for getting values from Parse Database and send it as props to a component where it will display the results as card

```
this.state = {
    items: null,
    loaded: false
};



componentDidMount() {
    this.queryValues()
}

queryValues = async id => {

    let cy = this;
    const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend('social');
    const query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo('A', 1);
    query.equalTo('B', 2);
    const results = await query.find().then(
        results => {
            cy.setState({
                items: results
                loaded: true,
            })
        },
        error => {}
    );

};

render() {
            return (

                {
                    this.state.loaded ?
                    <FlatList
                    data = {this.state.items}
                    renderItem = {
                        ({item}) => <SocialCard social={item} /> } /
                        >
                        : <
Text> Loading </Text>
}


                    );
                }
            }
```

In the  component here is the code

```
render() {
    const {
      social
    } = this.props;
    console.log(social)
    return (
      <Text>{this.props.}</Text>

    );
  }
```

the log show up like this

```
Object { 
"facebook": "https://facebook.com", 
"instagram": "https://Instagram.com", 
"placeName": "dazzlement", 
"snapchat": "https://snapchat.com", 
"twitter": "https://twitter.com", 
}
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet with your issues - those will work perfectly except the second one, which will error.

Comment: this is the code i used in React Native and still giving undefined.

Comment: let sam = {
  "facebook": "https://facebook.com",
  "instagram": "https://Instagram.com",
  "placeName": "dazzlement",
  "snapchat": "https://snapchat.com",
  "twitter": "https://twitter.com",
};
console.log(sam["placeName"]); and console.log(sam.placeName); both gives me "dazzlement"

Comment: that's what's strange on js browser it works fine, but in React Native on my end it's not. here is what i do, i get the object like this `{ "facebook": "facebook"...etc}` and then i store this object inside sam which will be let `sam={ "facebook": "facebook"...etc}`

Comment: try to use another name of a var, not a 'sam'. May be it is defined as a const smoewhere else and your environment works this way. Just a thought,,,

Comment: Also do `console.log(sam)` and see what you will see.

Comment: i tried and still undefined i tried this code `let sa = {theObjectIRecieved}
        console.log(sa.facebook)`

Comment: try `let sa = {theObjectIRecieved}; console.log(sa);` - this will show you if the object sa is assigned properly or not.

Comment: @HeroQu this is the log `Object {
  "objectName": Object {
    "facebook": "https://facebook.com",
    "instagram": "https://Instagram.com",
    "placeName": "dazzlement",
    "snapchat": "https://snapchat.com",
    "twitter": "https://twitter.com",
  },
}`

Comment: Not sure about the last Object... Try `let sa = {...}; console.log(Object.keys(sa));` - this will list the root level keys.

Comment: @HeroQu when i `console.log(sa.objectName)`  it return me the object values as `Object { "facebook": "https://facebook.com", "instagram": "https://Instagram.com", "placeName": "dazzlement", "snapchat": "https://snapchat.com", "twitter": "https://twitter.com", }` but when i do `console.log(sa.objectName.facebook)` it return undefined.

Comment: What about `console.log(Object.keys(sa));` ?

Comment: @HeroQu it return `Array [
  "objectName",
]`

Comment: Without a [MCVE] in the question itself, this question looks to be off-topic...

Comment: @JaromandaX i explained in the comments

Comment: That means it is not a javascript environment, it is something else. Some pre-intepretation...

Comment: @HeroQu i pass the object using props in React Native, isn't supposed to be passed as object ? unless i'm missing something in it any help would be appreciated

Comment: @JaromandaX Updated the question

Comment: @HeroQu Updated the question

Comment: @SandySmarue so instead of console.log(social); try console.log(social.placeName); or console.log(social["placeName"]); either should give you "dazzlement"

Comment: @GlenK for some reason it doesn't

Comment: @JaromandaX the result from the console for `JSON.stringify` is `{ 
"facebook": "https://facebook.com", 
"instagram": "https://Instagram.com", 
"placeName": "dazzlement", 
"snapchat": "https://snapchat.com", 
"twitter": "https://twitter.com", 
}`

Comment: @JaromandaX it's as you see in the code up there it's FlatList will show up when the loading is over and the loading is over when the query finished so basically it log the values but for some reason i can't get any value by key

Comment: Sorry, the code makes no sense *to me* - what does `this.props` have to do with `this.state.items` - that's a rhetorical question, I'm backing out of this question because it's out of my skill set

Comment: @JaromandaX if you look at the code, after the results are back from Parse database, it's stored inside items in the state using setstate({items: results}) and then the flatlist on renderitem will send the item to component social card, in that component i get the props which is the item sent by flatlist

Comment: rhetorical questions don't require answers

Comment: Just a tip. Look into React hooks as a replacement for class-based components. If you're just learning, you might as well learn the newest form though you may want to wait til you have a better grip on React components

Comment: @Chimera.Zen Thank you for the tip, i'll look into it :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198215/discussion-on-question-by-sandy-smarue-object-value-by-key-return-undefined).

Answer (score 0):

this should return all links

```
let sam = {
    facebook: 'facebook.com', // you don't need " " for facebook
    instagram: 'instagram.com'
}

for (let i in sam){
    console.log(sam[i])
}

sam.facebook // facebook.com
sam.instagram // instagram.com
```

Comment: why would i go in loop when i can just call them by key ?

Comment: well they all return the value you want.

Comment: this values is just dummy demo, the object values are over 30